# monaca localkit を通常サーバーへ

Tags: monaca

monaca localkitで作成したonsenUIのアプリをそのフォルダごとレンタルサーバーにうつしました。PCからみると、ちゃんと動いているのですが、iPhoneからみると、真っ白になります。
どこかにそういった制限記述があるのでしょうか？

また、iPhoneから見るにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか？
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1):

components/loader.js を読み込んでいるのかと思いますが、
loader.jsの最初の方にappの階層を取るために以下記述があります。

```
var relativePath = location.href.split("/www")[1];
```

これはwww/ディレクトリをベースに相対パスを取得するスクリプトの部分なのですが、
Webにアップロードする際にwww/配下のみアップロードするとこの部分がエラーになるようです。
web用にスクリプトを書き換えるか、wwwディレクトリを含めてアップロードすると解消されると思いますがいかがでしょうか。

＝＝＝追記＝＝＝

もう1点気付きましたので投稿します。
loader.jsを読み込み終わる前に並列で他のmonaca bowerで登録しているプラグインの操作などを含めるスクリプトが走ると未定義なりなんなりでエラーがでる可能性が高いようです。

試しにloader.jsの後にloader.cssを設置し、その後に通常のjsを設置してみて動作確認をしてみて下さい。

※ 擬似的にリクエストのブロックで読み込み調整していますが、これが原因だと確定した場合、出来るのであればスクリプト読込後のコールバック等にした方がいいと思います。